Sizeof equality of direct members vs inherited members
Does the C++ standard have anything to say about the size equality of the following?
struct AB
{
    int a;
    int b;
} 

Or
struct A
{
    int a
};
    
struct B : public A
{
    int b;
}

Is sizeof(AB) == sizeof(B), or is it undefined?

I think object layout with inheritance is implementation specific.

The sub-class can be partially-overlapping, reusing padding from the base class. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52818411/will-the-padding-of-base-class-be-copied-into-the-derived-class Of course in your particular case there is no padding

In theory they will be the same.  No sane compiler would pad out A to make it larger than sizeof(int) and since both classes are standard layout the first member is guaranteed to have the same address as the class it is contained in. This means b should be placed directly after a in the second example.  That said, this is just what a sane compiler would do.

B is not a standard-layout class (one of the requirements is that "only one class in the hierarchy has non-static data members", which B doesn't satisfy). The standard provides some guarantees for standard-layout classes, but pretty much none for classes that are not standard-layout. In practice, AB and B would have the same size with any sane compiler. If this property is important for your program, you can static_assert it.

Sizes of all types (except char types which have size 1 by definition) are implementation-defined.    Although it is possible that - for some implementation -  sizeof(AB) == sizeof(A),  that is not guaranteed, and may vary between implementations.   There is a good chance - but not really useful - that sizeof(AB) >= sizeof(A) will always be true though.   Practically, writing code that relies on sizes of anything (other than char types) having some fixed value, or writing code that relies on some relationship between sizes of distinct types, is called a "code smell" for a reason.
